# Oracle Data Provider adapter fill takes forever

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a .net (C#) DAL layer in my application which uses Oracle Data Provider (The System.Data.Oracleclient Version) to Retrieve results from the DB.

I have a problem that somtimes queries which take seconds to complete when executed via PLSQL take forever to complete with the method `Adapter.Fill(Table)` this is causing us lots of problems and we have no idea what's causing it.

Any Idea anyone? help will be greatly appriciated

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434654/why-is-oracledataadapter-fill-very-slow

Comment: The dupe does not have a definitive answer but does provide a much better detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

When you say it "takes seconds to complete when executed via PLSQL" is that the time to return all rows selected by the query, just the first 20 or so? How many rows are returned by the query in total?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Toad to run the query it will return a sub set of data and then continue filling until complete.  Are you querying text data?  What happens if you change your result to a count(*) versus the actual fields?  Does that change the timings?